# jScrollPane and window resize triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, resize, jscrollpane

I'm wondering if this is possible. I've got jScrollPane set up on a div on a site, but I want this function to destroy if the screen width is less or equal to 580px. If you resize your browser larger than 580px once it has been destroyed, it will reinitialise.

There's some info on destroy/initialise for the plugin here http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/destroy.html

So I'm thinking I need to hook this up to a resize function, rather than the click trigger in the demo. Something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will fire when document is ready:
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() <= 580) {
            // if smaller or equal
            $('.project-content-parent-container').jScrollPane().destroy();
        } else {
            // if larger
            INITIALISE??
        }
    }).resize(); // This will simulate a resize to trigger the initial run.
});
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually worked this out and solved it with the below. Hope this helps anyone else in need.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() < 580) {
        var element = $('.project-content-parent-container').jScrollPane({});
        var api = element.data('jsp');
        api.destroy();
    } else {
        $('.project-content-parent-container').jScrollPane();
    }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() < 580) {
        var element = $('.project-content-parent-container').jScrollPane({});
        var api = element.data('jsp');
        api.destroy();
    } else {
        $('.project-content-parent-container').jScrollPane();
    }
});
```